# Is there a WordPress plugin for check in/ check out?

Tags: wordpress

I'm designing a website for a gym and I need to be able to track the time spent by the customers. I am looking for a plugin (hopefully) that will allow customers to check in with their pin # and check out. Also, are there any pre-built plugins for managing gym memberships? Activities include adding new members, managing membership, membership renewal and reminder emails?

Answer (score 0):

I would check out WPGYM if you haven't already

https://wordpress.org/plugins/gym-studio-membership-management/

The only thing it doesn't have that I'm aware of is the the ability to track time spent in the gym.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. If you cannot find a resource that does what you want it to, then you'll need to write your own.